# Telemetry_xevents session and auto_stats

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I've noticed on a number of instances that the telemetry_xevents session is full of auto_stats events.

[image]

The statistic is not being updated. I've even disabled auto update statistics and auto update asynchronous statistics on development databases but I am still receiving these messages.

Can anyone shed some light on the **Loading stats without updating** status message?

The environments are SQL Server 2017 CU21.

Comment: I'm curious to see of anybody can tell us what these are. FWIW, I had to filter quite a bit to make this event useful, as you can see in the definition of me "Looking for strange" trace: https://karaszi.com/looking-for-strange